# Writing to GCS fails randomly, usually after the first write

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I write a file under `/tmp`. This code is running in docker container. The write to GCS succeeds. Code looks like below

```
    public String  writeToBucket(String id, File file, String bucket, String fileName) {
        l.info("attempt to write to bucket {}, file {}",bucket,fileName);
        BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucket,fileName);
        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
        try {
            Blob b = storage.createFrom(blobInfo,file.toPath());
            if(b == null) {
                l.error("blob is null ");
            } else {
                l.info("blob is not null, wrote to bucket {}, filename {}",
                        b.getBucket(), fileName);
            }
            return "wrote";
        } catch (IOException | StorageException e) {
            throw new MyException(String.format("Failed to write to bucket for id  %s",id),e);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            l.error("could not write to bucket {}, file {} exception thrown {}",bucket, fileName, ex);
            throw new MyException("could not write to bucket {}, file {} exception thrown {}",ex);
        }
    }
```

The first write succeeds. When this function is called subsequently, the write fails, and the `File` instance is new each time.
It fails with below error

> Caused by: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Client side data loss detected. Attempt to append to a resumable session with an offset higher than the backend has

Does it somehow think I am doing a multipart upload or something?